# How to join array of array locations with zero location?

Tags: swift, core-location

This is what I try to achieve:

```
let a = CLLocation(latitude: 10, longitude: 20)
let b = CLLocation(latitude: 10, longitude: 40)
let c = CLLocation(latitude: 10, longitude: 60)
let d = CLLocation(latitude: 10, longitude: 80)

let aa = [a, b]
let bb = [c, d]

let zero = CLLocation(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)

let cc = [aa, bb].joined(separator: zero)
```

I need to have something like this:

```
let output = [a, b, zero, c, d]
```

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Answer (score 2):

The separator must be an array too:

```
let cc = [aa, bb].joined(separator: [zero])
print(Array(cc))
```

Comment: More specifically, the value passed to `joined` must be the same type as the type in the array which is `[CLLocation]` in this case.

Comment: Did you try: `let cc = [aa, bb].joined(separator: [zero])`